# Need a simple overlay or tooltip

Tags: javascript

I need a tooltip or overlay to appear onmouseover and disappear onmouseout displaying the text thats inside the cell.  I can get the text out of the cell no problem.  How do i make that into a tooltip or overlay?  The problem is this needs to be extremely lightweight.  No JQuery library loads. Css can be javascript controlled so no css declarations other than javascript handling it.  Is there a way with a few lines of code to create some kind of box (background color would be nice if code kept small) that appears onmouseover with the cell text and disappears onmouseout?

```
<td onmouseover="this.value; what else here?">
```

Comment: `Mousein` and `-out` events are [messed up between browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html), you will need some little helper functions for handling them. Or simply use the `title` attribute :-)

Comment: @Bergi: What do you mean by "messed up"?

Comment: I've added a link to it. See also [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t017)

Comment: @Bergi: I still dont see how those event-handlers are messed up?

Comment: [mouseover](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseover) and [mouseout](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#link8) are not really made for tooltip features, they need additional conditioning.

Comment: @Bergi's point is that you are going to have either a very complex solution to deal with multiple browsers/OSs, or else you will have to load a pre-designed (heavy) solution.  Remember that you will also have to deal with borders of the screen, browser, window, div, and whatever else, to make sure that the tip remains visible.  There is no easy *and* lightweight fix . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td onmouseover="this.title = this.value;">
```

There were dozens of solutions however this is the simplest and thats what i was looking for.